# RabbitMQ on Docker. Not creating cookies / can't find host?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I'm trying to follow a basic tutorial to start using RabbitMQ, converting from "docker run" to docker-compose.  http://josuelima.github.io/docker/rabbitmq/cluster/2017/04/19/setting-up-a-rabbitmq-cluster-on-docker.html

Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    rabbit1:
        image: rabbitmq:3.6.6-management
        restart: unless-stopped
        hostname: rabbit1
        ports:
            - "4369:4369"
            - "5672:5672"
            - "15672:15672"
            - "25672:25672"
            - "35197:35197"
        environment: 
            - RABBITMQ_USE_LONGNAME=true
            - RABBITMQ_LOGS=/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit.log
        volumes:
            - "/nfs/docker/rabbit/data1:/var/lib/rabbitmq"
            - "/nfs/docker/rabbit/data1/logs:/var/log/rabbitmq"
```

Trying to see if I can connect (and also remove the guest account) I get this error.

```
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@rabbit1: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@rabbit1]

rabbit@rabbit1:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on rabbit1
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
  * suggestion: hostname mismatch?
  * suggestion: is the cookie set correctly?
  * suggestion: is the Erlang distribution using TLS?

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-41@rabbit1.no-domain'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: WjJle1otRdldm4Wso6HGfg==
```

Looking at the persistant data, it doesn't appear to be creating a cookie (whether or not I use the RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE variable) and I'm not convinced that the domain is being handled properly.

RabbitMQ docs are useless for this.

Comment: Why do you think `RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE` is valid to use? It's not mentioned in that tutorial nor the RabbitMQ docs (which are far from useless).

Comment: I've tried it with and without that line.  The "suggestion: is the cookie set correctly?" led me to try that.  Again, I get the same result both with it and without it.